# JDialog unmovable form JTable cell editor

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I have customized the `JTable` cell editor in order to allow enter data from `JDialog` frame. I have used an editable combobox for that, I have added an `ActionListener` for combobox to display The dialog.

I have got my `JDialog` visible, but I want to make it unmovable, so the user can't move it.

Here is my code so far,

```
package VIEW;

import VIEW.statManager.SearchProduitEvent;
import VIEW.statManager.SearchProduitEventListener;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuEvent;
import javax.swing.event.PopupMenuListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;


public class ProduitCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements       TableCellEditor,ActionListener, SearchProduitEventListener {

    private JComboBox combo;
    private SearchProduitUi searchProduitUi;
    private String value = "value";
    public ProduitCellEditor() {

        combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.setEditable(true);
        combo.setActionCommand("combo");

        searchProduitUi = new SearchProduitUi();
        searchProduitUi.setSearchProduitEventListener(this);
        searchProduitUi.setSize(500,300);
        searchProduitUi.setLocationRelativeTo(combo);
    }


    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return value;
     }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable jtable, Object o, boolean bln, int i, int i1) {
        return combo;
     }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Point comboPosition = combo.getLocationOnScreen();
         searchProduitUi.setLocationRelativeTo(combo);
         searchProduitUi.setLocation(comboPosition.x ,comboPosition.y + combo.getHeight());
         searchProduitUi.setVisible(true);

     }

    @Override
    public void searchDialogEventOccured(SearchProduitEvent ev) {
        value = ev.getProduit().getDesignation();
        fireEditingStopped();

      }
  }
```

Comment: Set the dialog undecorated...

Comment: i have do searchProduitUi.setUndecorated(true); but no thing happens.

Comment: [In case of Dialog semantics] Please note that I, as a user, would want to shoot you if you prevent me from moving windows around, no matter which type of window. Often enough it happens that the information required for the dialog is hidden behind the dialog, and if you do not let me move the dialog around... on most window managers I could still move the window behind the dialog, but on out-of-the-box MS Windows, I'd be lost. So, I think what you want to achieve might be questionable from a usability perspective.

Comment: [In case of Popup semantics] If your Dialog is just representing a temporary thing, not a true Dialog, consider what if the Window is scrolled or moved? Your dialog's position would no longer be correct. Consider using `JGlassPane` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`JDialog#setUndecorated` will remove the frame decorations, including the close/minimise/maximise controls and make it impossible for the user to move the window.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public Test1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                content.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 8, 8, 8));
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello world");
                content.add(label);

                JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
                dialog.setUndecorated(true);
                dialog.setTitle("Testing");
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setContentPane(content);
                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i got this litte error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The dialog is displayable.

Comment: You dialog has already been displayed on the screen or attached to a native peer (done other methods create a connection to a native peer), best to do this as soon as you create an instance of the dialog, before you do anything else